# Events and CDN receipts

Tags: cdn-tax-receipts

Is it possible to send CDN receipts automatically upon event registration without replacing the event receipt code with the CDN receipt one ?

Answer (score 1):

There is the "Attach receipts to automated workflow messages" setting in the CDN tax settings.